# How can I change each pixel's RGB value on bitmap image with python?

Tags: python, image, bitmap, rgb

I want to read each pixel's RGB value and change it on bitmap image.
How can I do it with python? What library should I use?

Answer (score 1):

The module you are looking for is [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/)

Comment: Specifically, [Image.getdata()](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.getdata) and `Image.putdata()`.